# Accessing Windows Admin Center behind nginx

Tags: windows, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, wac

Has anyone successfully put windows admin center behind nginx reverse-proxy? I'm not sure if it is possible would like some guidance if it is.

Comment: Me too looking for that's, but behind Cloudflare. I got 400 and i'm sure is related due to NTLM. That's maybe can help you https://caddy.community/t/doesnt-work-when-reverse-proxy-windows-admin-center/6408 or https://community.cloudflare.com/t/400-bad-request-with-cloudflare-ssl-on-windows-admin-center/134501

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but requires NGINX-PLUS (Paid/Commercial) to gain access to the "ntlm_auth" function.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ntlm

Caddy seems to be the best option at the moment, but they are lacking documentation. I have started a thread. It may be possible to use Caddy + NGinx, but as I haven't gotten Caddy Working yet... I can't confirm.

https://caddy.community/t/guide-for-windows-admin-center-proxy-from-linux-vm-to-server-core/7192/5

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream wac.mydomain.com {
        server 10.10.100.199:443;
        keepalive 16;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name wac.*;

        ssl_certificate           /ssl/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key       /ssl/cert.key;

       location / {
           proxy_pass https://wac.mydomain.com;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Connection "";
       }

}
```

Comment: I have this running with Windows Admin Center in HA on a multi-node S2D hyper-v cluster. The WAC role is given a static IP resource.